# How to multiple fetch data expressJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I want to display chatbot and facebook data at the same time. how to display it? because when I try to run in the browser but it does not appear anything. I've tried to look it up on stackoverflow but did not get the right reference

route.js

```
app.get('/cpanel/facebook', function(req, res) {
        if (req.session.user == null) {
            res.redirect('/cpanel/login');
        }   else {
            CB.getAllRecords( function(e, chatbot) {
                res.render('cpanel/facebook', { udata : req.session.user, chatbot : chatbot });
            });
            FBM.getAllRecords( function(e, facebook) {
                res.render('cpanel/facebook', { udata : req.session.user, facebook : facebook });
            });
        }
    });
```

facebook.js

```
var facebook = db.collection('facebook');

exports.addNewFacebook = function(newData, callback) {
    facebook.findOne({accesstoken:newData.accesstoken}, function(e, o) {
        if (o) {
            callback('accesstoken-taken');
        }   else {
            facebook.insert(newData, {safe: true}, callback);
        }
    });
}

exports.getAllRecords = function(callback) {
    facebook.find().toArray(
        function(e, res) {
            if (e) callback(e)
            else callback(null, res)
        }
    );
}
```

chatbot.js

```
var chatbot = db.collection('chatbot');

exports.addNewChatBot = function(newData, callback) {
    chatbot.insert(newData, {safe: true}, callback);
}

exports.getAllRecords = function(callback) {
    chatbot.find().toArray(
        function(e, res) {
            if (e) callback(e)
            else callback(null, res)
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Short answer.  Use the promises interface instead of the plain callback insterface with your database and then use `Promise.all()` to track when both requests are done.  You will want to switch to promises for managing asynchronous operations because it's way simpler to manage multiple async operations when using promises.

Comment: do you have a sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier way to manage asynchronous operations in node.js, especially when you have more than one operation that you want to coordinate is to use Promises instead of plain callbacks.  And, fortunately, mongodb supports a promise-based interface for all its asynchronous operations now.

So, first change your methods to return a promise instead of taking a callback:

```
var chatbot = db.collection('chatbot');

exports.getAllRecords = function() {
    return chatbot.find().toArray();
}

var facebook = db.collection('facebook');

exports.getAllRecords = function() {
    return facebook.find().toArray();
}
```

Then, you can use those promises with `Promise.all()` to coordinate:

```
app.get('/cpanel/facebook', function(req, res) {
    if (req.session.user == null) {
        res.redirect('/cpanel/login');
    } else {
        Promise.all([CB.getAllRecords(), FBM.getAllRecords()]).then(results => {
            res.render('cpanel/facebook', { udata : req.session.user, chatbot : results[0], facebook: results[1]});
        }).catch(err => {
            // render some error page here
            res.sendStatus(500);
        });
    }
});
```

For a call to just a single function that returns a promise, you can use `.then()`:

```
app.get('/cpanel/facebook', function(req, res) {
    if (req.session.user == null) {
        res.redirect('/cpanel/login');
    } else {
        FBM.getAllRecords().then(results => {
            res.render('cpanel/facebook', { udata : req.session.user, facebook: results});
        }).catch(err => {
            // render some error page here
            res.sendStatus(500);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried to follow the code you gave, but the error appears: SyntaxError: Unexpected token>

Comment: @ArifFirmansyah - On what line of code is that error?  Are you sure you copied the code here exactly?  What version of node.js are you running?

Comment: sorry I wrong copy paste. now can run in browser. i want to ask too, does promise.all it need npm install --save promise-all?
because I do that

Comment: @ArifFirmansyah - `Promise.all()` is part of ES6 and is built into recent versions of node.js so it does not need to be separately installed.

Comment: I want to ask again, how to display single data? for example just chatbot only

Comment: @ArifFirmansyah - I added one more example to my answer for a single function call, but you really should read up about how promises work.

Comment: I want to ask again, how to render and fetch data with url like this:

/cpanel/chat-bot/:id

chatbot collection
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2f8c2d2bb4710c0ab9fb7c"),
    "botname" : "Facebook",
    "callbackurl" : "http://facebook.com",
    "verifytoken" : "123456789",
    "accesstoken" : "987654321"
}

Comment: @ArifFirmansyah - In the spirit of how this site works, I've answered your original question (and several others too).  If you have a new question, then please post a new question and fully explain what you're trying to do.  From that comment, I don't understand at all what you're asking so it needs a lot more explanation in a new question.

Comment: Ok, maybe you can help answer my question in the following link :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860998/express-js-display-data-by-id