# Express JS Display Data By ID

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I use mongodb with collection structure as follows:

chatbot collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2f8edf84b906480af0d121"),
    "botname" : "Welcome Chat",
    "description" : "Welcome Chat",
    "status" : "Inactive"
}
```

route.js

```
app.get('/cpanel/chat-bot/:id', function(req, res) {
        if (req.session.user == null) {
            res.redirect('/cpanel/login');
        }   else {
            CB.getAllRecords().then(results => {
            res.render('cpanel/chat-bot/:id', { udata : req.session.user, chatbot: results});
        }).catch(err => {
                res.sendStatus(500);
            });
        }
    });
```

index.ejs

```
<ul class="menu-sidebar">
        <% for(var i = 0; i < chatbot.length; i++) { %>
          <li>
            <a href="/cpanel/chat-bot/:id"><span class="fa fa-circle-o"></span><%= chatbot[i].botname %></a>
          </li>
        <% } %>
      </ul>
```

how to display data chatbot by id from mongodb? when I click url 1 (/cpanel/chat-bot/1) it will show data id 1 from mongodb, when I click url 2 (/cpanel/chat-bot/2) it will show data id 2 from mongodb? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you configure a route like

```
app.get('/cpanel/chat-bot/:id', ...)
```

The `:id` part of the route says that you want to match any value for that part of the path and then Express will put whatever was matched into `req.params.id`.  So, if you want to use that `id` value as part of your database query, you need to use `req.params.id` in your database query in order to select only the desired data from your database.

In addition, you do NOT use `:id` in the render path so remove it from here:

```
res.render('cpanel/chat-bot/:id', ...);
```

That should just be a path to your template file (whatever the filename of the template is):

```
res.render('cpanel/chat-bot', ...);
```

---

You don't disclose much about your data in the database so we can't really help with how you would use the `req.params.id` value to select the desired data from your database.  I presume you would use it in a query of some sort.

Comment: can you give a sample, please?

Comment: examples of how to use req.params.id that suits my case?

Comment: @ArifFirmansyah - Are you asking how to write a database query using `req.params.id`?  If so, what do you want the database query to do and what data do you have in the database?  I'm not a mongodb expert myself.